# Radio buttons break with React JSX - Expressions must have one parent element

Tags: reactjs, forms, components, mapping, jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { EmployeeList } from '../EmployeeList/EmployeeList';

export default function EmployeeMenu(props) {
    
    const [employeeList, setEmployeeList] = useState(() => new EmployeeList());
    useEffect(() => employeeList.getEmployees(), [employeeList]);

    const handleEmployeeChange = (event, data) => {
        props.setEmployee(event.target.value);
        console.log(event.target.value);
    }
    
    function EmployeeMenu() {
        let temp = employeeList.employees.map((employee) => (
        <div>
            <input type="radio" id={employee.phone_number} name="employee_name" value={employee.first_name} />
            <label htmlFor={employee.phone_number}>{employee.first_name} {employee.last_name}</label>
        </div>
        ));
        return temp;
    }

    return(
        <form onChange={handleEmployeeChange}>
            <EmployeeMenu />
        </form>
  );
}
```

[code produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQO3p.png)

This is what the code produces. It's close to what I wanted to accomplish, but my radio buttons do not check/uncheck when I select different employees.

That's because I have each input and label inside a separate div when I map the information from the employeeList array. But if I don't wrap them, I get "JSX expressions must have one parent element". Does anyone have any advice on how I could better map radio buttons from an array so that they remain inside the same form group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the "form" element, it's must be type of form element(input).but div is not the type of form element, so it's has a warning.
the code in below is right:

```
<form onChange={handleEmployeeChange}>
     <input type="radio" id={employee.phone_number} name="employee_name" value={employee.first_name} />
     <label htmlFor={employee.phone_number}>{employee.first_name} {employee.last_name}</label>
 </form>
```

if you want to package it as a component;
your code should like:

```
function EmployeeMenu() {
    let temp = employeeList.employees.map((employee) => (
    <>
        <input type="radio" id={employee.phone_number} name="employee_name" value={employee.first_name} />
        <label htmlFor={employee.phone_number}>{employee.first_name} {employee.last_name}</label>
    </>
    ));
    return temp;
}

return(
    <form onChange={handleEmployeeChange}>
        <EmployeeMenu />
    </form>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `EmployeeMenu` function is treated as a *FC* (*functional component*). You should either

- wrap the returned `temp` with *react fragment*:

  ```
  return <>{temp}</>;
  ```
- or just call it as a function, not like a component:

  ```
  <form onChange={handleEmployeeChange}>
     {EmployeeMenu()}
  </form>
  ```